# Parameter values

Tags: sql, ms-access

can anyone tell me why the following query is asking me for parameter values. It should be (or at least I want to) populating the table with data 'from' where it's pulling it from:

```
SELECT [BILLING_REJECTS_orig].[ORG NBR] AS BK,
    [BILLING_REJECTS_orig].[ACCOUNT NUMBER] AS ACCT,
    [BILLING_REJECTS_orig].APPL AS AP,
    [BILLING_REJECTS_orig].[ACCOUNT NAME] AS [ACCT NAME],
    [BILLING_REJECTS_orig].[TMO NAME],
    IIf(Len(DatePart("m", [BILLING_REJECTS_orig]![REPORT DATE])) = 1, Year([BILLING_REJECTS_orig]![REPORT DATE]) & "-" & "0" & Month([BILLING_REJECTS_orig]![REPORT DATE]), Year([BILLING_REJECTS_orig]![REPORT DATE]) & "-" & Month([BILLING_REJECTS_orig]![REPORT DATE])) AS [ACTIVITY MONTH]
INTO Billing_Rejects_Orig
FROM dbo_BILLING_REJECTS_DEPT,
    TM_Report_Date
WHERE (
        ((Year([Billing_Rejects_Orig]![REPORT DATE])) = Year([TM_Report_Date]![Report_Date]))
        AND ((Month([Billing_Rejects_Orig]![REPORT DATE])) = Month([TM_Report_Date]![Report_Date]))
        );
```

Comment: Shouldn't you select the fields from `dbo_BILLING_REJECTS_DEPT`, not `BILLING_REJECTS_orig`. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Thanks, JNevill, - I don't believe so. So, this is in Access db., the dbo_BIlling_rejects_DEPT is linked table to SQL server db. and I want it to update the table called BILLING_REJECTS_orig that is in access database too. Thanks again for the response.

Comment: You are exactly right. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

As @WEI_DBA points out with incorrect reference to table, consider using table aliases as shown with `b` and `t`. This cuts down SQL code and is a helpful tool in maintainability as you can then switch out the table name in `FROM` or `JOIN` clauses without a whole re-write of query, assuming same structured table.

Especially in MS Access being a default backend database (Jet/ACE) that can be switched out with other RDBMS's (SQL Server, MySQL, etc.) and occasionally used for prototyping, table aliases can help in migration between both linked and local tables.

```
SELECT b.[ORG NBR] AS BK,
       b.[ACCOUNT NUMBER] AS ACCT,
       b.APPL AS AP,
       b.[ACCOUNT NAME] AS [ACCT NAME],
       b.[TMO NAME],
       IIf(Len(DatePart('m', b.[REPORT DATE])) = 1, 
           Year(b.[REPORT DATE]) & '-' & '0' & Month(b.[REPORT DATE]), 
           Year(b.[REPORT DATE]) & '-' & Month(b.[REPORT DATE])) AS [ACTIVITY MONTH]
INTO Billing_Rejects_Orig
FROM dbo_BILLING_REJECTS_DEPT b, 
     TM_Report_Date t
WHERE (
       ((Year(b.[REPORT DATE])) = Year(t.[Report_Date]))
   AND ((Month(b.[REPORT DATE])) = Month(t.[Report_Date]))
      );
```